# IEnumerable Best Practice of removing int item

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a IEmunerable list with N items for example: 23, 1, 38.....

The needed logic is, when looping thru the list:

1:    find if 1exist

2:    if 1 exist, find 2

3:    if 2 exist, find 3

4: If 3 exist, remove 3 from the current list.

My current approach is:

```
foreach(var x in someIntList)
{
    if(x==1)
    {
        if(someIntList.Any(y => y==2))
        {
            if(someIntList.Any(z => z==3))
            {
                //This is the shortest code i can think of, but apparently its wrong. Error saying there is no Except method for IEmunerable<Int> ?
                someIntList = someIntList.Except(3);

            }

        }

    }   

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear why you're looping to start with, or using `Any` instead of `Contains`:

```
if (someIntList.Contains(1) && someIntList.Contains(2) && someIntList.Contains(3))
{
    someIntList = someIntList.Where(x => x != 3); // Possibly with ToList()?
}
```

You probably *don't* want to use `Except` as that's a set-based operation - if your original list contains duplicates, they will be removed if you use `Except`.

Note that this will remove *all* occurrences of 3 - is that what you want, or do you just want to remove the *first* occurrence of 3?

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass `IEnumerable<int>` to except, like this

```
someIntList = someIntList.Except(new[] {3});
```

read more about Except on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

To remove better use this, I can't imagine shorter version:

```
if(someIntList.Contains(1)&&someIntList.Contains(2)&&someIntList.Contains(3))
{
    someIntList.Remove(3); // **if it's a list**
    someIntList = someIntList.Except(3); //**if it's a IEnumerable**
}
```

Comment: ok. But `.Any(y => y==1 && y==2 && y==3)` will never be true :)

Answer (score 2):

Snippet

```
var x = new List<int> {5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
        if(x.Contains(1) && x.Contains(2) && x.Contains(3)) x.Remove(3);
```

Just in case...

```
IEnumerable<int> y = new List<int> {5,4,3,2,1};
```

So if you are getting an IEnumerable from your method.

```
var x = y.ToList()
```

If you need to remove all, x.RemoveAll(z=>z == 3);

Comment: That won't work with `IEnumerable<int>` though, as there's no `Remove` method (and no extension method for it).

Comment: Also, `Remove` will only remove a *single* element with that value - I had interpreted the OP as wanting to remove *all* 3s, but I could be wrong.

Comment: IEnumerable can be casted to a list... then removeall does exist.

Comment: It can only be cast to a list if it *is* a list. You could call `ToList` to start with though, if that's what you meant.